# Prove the following equivalence (rationals)

Tags: proof-writing

I'm working on trying to prove the following equivalence for all x in real numbers:

$x$ is rational $\leftrightarrow x - 5$ is rational $\leftrightarrow x/3$ is rational

I know i need to prove each one individually such as:
$$x\,\,is\,\,rational \rightarrow x - 5 \,\,is\,\,rational\\
x-5\,\,is\,\,rational \rightarrow x/3\\
x/3 \,\,is\,\,rational \rightarrow x \,\,is\,\,rational\\$$

1. I started by assuming if $x = \frac{p}{q} $  then  $x-5= \frac{p}{q}-5$
   which is still a rational.
2. Then if $x - 5 = \frac{p}{q}$ then $\frac{x}{3} = \frac{\frac{p}{q}}{3}$ which is still a rational (Is there a proper way to prove this algebraically, I feel like it might be insufficient proof to just keep saying it is a rational).
3. After this I am very unsure what to do to get from step 2 to 3. I've looked at a bunch of examples but I suck at proving rationals. Would it be something like if $3*\frac{x}{3} = \frac{\frac{p}{q}}{3}*3$ then $x = \frac{p}{q} $

---

**Edit:**

1. Assume x is rational   $p \rightarrow q$
   x = $\frac{p}{q}$
   Prove x-5 is rational
   substitute x :  $x-5 = \frac{p-5q}{q}$   : x-5 is a rational
2. Assume x-5 is rational   $q \rightarrow r$
   x-5 = $\frac{p}{q}$
   solve for x:   $x=\frac{p-5q}{q}$
   Prove $\frac{x}{3}$
   substitude for x:   $\frac{x}{3} = \frac{\frac{p-5q}{q}}{3}$   : $\frac{x}{3}$   is rational because the numerator and denominator are rationals
3. Assume $\frac{x}{3}$ is rational   $r \rightarrow p$
   $\frac{x}{3} = \frac{p}{q}$
   solve for x = $\frac{\frac{p-5q}{q}}{3}$
   Prove x is a rational
   we already proved x is a rational in the second step, because the quotient of two rationals is always a quotient.

Comment: You don't need to prove each individually in both directions.  It suffices to show the three one-way implications:  $x$ rational $\implies x-5$ rational,   $x-5$ rational $\implies x/3$ rational, and $x/3$ rational $\implies x$ rational.

Comment: You need to be careful to not confuse what $\frac{p}{q}$ represents.  In your second statement for example, you said that $x-5=\frac{p}{q}$ and then $\frac{x}{3}=\frac{\frac{p}{q}}{3}$, but that is incorrect.  Given your assumption that $x-5=\frac{p}{q}$ that would mean that $\frac{x-5}{3}=\frac{\frac{p}{q}}{3}$.  Another nitpick is that at this level of difficulty what you should end with is very specifically an integer divided by another nonzero integer in order to show that a number is rational.  $\frac{p}{q}-5$ for example should be written $\frac{p-5q}{q}$

Comment: @JMoravitz I took what you said and edited my work. Can you please tell me if I did it right now that I changed some stuff around?

Comment: You still have errors and you have not in several places fully reduced to a simple fraction, where there is only one fraction bar.  Yes, a rational divided by a nonzero rational is rational, but given that this is such an introductory question, you should show it by *first principles* and not rely on results like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(i)\implies (ii)$

Suppose $x$ is rational.  Then $x=\frac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p,q$ with $q\neq 0$.

> We have then $x-5=\frac{p}{q}-5=\frac{p}{q}-\frac{5q}{q}=\frac{p-5q}{q}$ and noting that $p-5q$ is an integer (*since integers are closed under addition and multiplication*) and $q\neq 0$ as before, we have successfully written $x-5$ as a ratio of two integers with the integer in the denominator nonzero and is therefore rational.

---

$(ii)\implies (iii)$

Suppose $x-5$ is rational.  Then $x-5=\frac{p}{q}$ for some integers $p,q$ with $q\neq 0$.

Then $\frac{x}{3}=\frac{1}{3}\left((x-5)+5\right)=\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{p}{q}+5\right)=\frac{1}{3}(\frac{p+5q}{q})=\frac{p+5q}{3q}$ and noting that $p+5q$ is an integer since integers are closed under addition and multiplication and that $3q$ is a nonzero integer since both $3$ and $q$ are both nonzero integers and the product of two nonzero integers is again a nonzero integer, we see then that we can write $\frac{x}{3}$ as a ratio of two integers with the integer in the denominator nonzero and is therefore rational.

---

$(iii)\implies (i)$

Similar to the other cases.